# Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled / Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'JSON'

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, xcode12

Sup, everyone... i hope you're doing good. Well, I've being coding for a short period of time and this bug came across, does anyone knows how to solve it? The intention is to have this 'file' which is a 'Auth Service', to communicate with a 'user data service' when the user present all of the information to this chat app.

***The Third Image that I uploaded is what the I've being taught to to do it.****

```
AF.request(URL_USER_ADD, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response) in

  switch response.result {
          case .success(let result):
             if let json = result as? Data {
                guard let data = response.data else { return }
                guard let json = JSON(data: data) else { return }
                let id = json["_id"].stringValue
                let color = json["avatarColor"].stringValue
                let avatarName = json["avatarName"].stringValue
                let email = json["email"].stringValue
                let name = json["name"].stringValue
             }

            case .failure(let result):
                completion(false)
                debugPrint(response.result as Any)

                UserDataService.instance.setUserData(id: _id, color: avatarColor, avatarName: avatarName, email: email, name: name)
                completion(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[error01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMAYp.png)

[error02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEb43.png)

[lesson taught](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djt9r.png)

Comment: The errors mean exactly what they say. The `JSON`  initialiser does not return `nil` if the decoding fails. Rather, it `throws` an exception. You need to wrap the call in a `do/try/catch` clause so that you can handle any error

Comment: The second error just seems to be misplaced code; you are trying to access local variables declared in the `.success` case outside of that code block.  The variable name is also `id`, not `_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the `JSON` initialiser `throws`, so the compiler is telling you you need to handle this.

You are also trying to access local variables declare in the `.success` code block outside of that block, so they are unknown. You also have the wrong name for the `id` variable.

```
AF.request(URL_USER_ADD, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response) in

  switch response.result {
          case .success(let result):
             if let json = result as? Data {
                guard let data = response.data else { return }
                do {
                    let json = try JSON(data: data)
                    let id = json["_id"].stringValue
                    let color = json["avatarColor"].stringValue
                    let avatarName = json["avatarName"].stringValue
                    let email = json["email"].stringValue
                    let name = json["name"].stringValue
                    UserDataService.instance.setUserData(id: id, color: avatarColor, avatarName: avatarName, email: email, name: name)
                    completion(true)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                    completion(false)
                }
            }

            case .failure(let result):
                completion(false)
                debugPrint(response.result as Any)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a point of style, a completion handler that simply returns `true` or `false` isn't particularly useful as it doesn't provide any information on *what* went wrong when `false` is returned, but since you mention a lesson, I will assume that this isn't your design choice.

Comment: no it isn't. I'm just trying to replicate what he asked me to do it. Even reading as much as I can, I don't  understand much, but I'm deeply trying!

Answer (score 0):

It seems this bit of code is part of a popular programming course or something, because I answered [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66913097/15280114).

Your teacher's code is wrong because it doesn't handle the throwing initializer for `JSON`.  Perhaps it was right for some earlier version of SwiftyJSON.  In any case @Paulw1's answer gets you most of the way there.  The problem is that simply calling `try JSON(data: data)` will be a problem if the surrounding function isn't marked as `throws`.  Given that you're already bailing out with some other errors (such as failing to unwrap optionals), and that is apparently acceptable because it's what your teacher's code does, you can do it like this:

```swift
guard let json = try? JSON(data: data) else { return }
```

So here's the deal on `try` and it's variants.

#### `try`

For `try`, either the surrounding function must be marked `throws`, in which case, any error thrown will propagate up to the caller, or you have to explicitly handle it in a `do...catch`.

So if we assume that your function is called `foo`, it would need to be declared something like this:

```swift
 func foo(...) throws -> ReturnTypeIfAny
```

or you have to wrap the `try` in a `do...catch` like this:

```swift
let json: JSON
do {
    json = try JSON(data: data)
}
catch {
    // do something with the error
}
```

#### `try?`

`try?` returns `nil` if the thing that can throw does throw.  So you handle it like any optional return type.

```swift
guard let json = try? JSON(data: data) else { return }
```

or

```swift
if let json = try? JSON(data: data)
{
   // code that access json goes here
}
```

#### `try!`

You probably want to avoid this one most of the time.  `try!` completely ignores the possibility of an error being thrown and crashes if one is thrown.  Use it *only* when you are sure that even though the function you're calling is marked as `throws`, you know it can't actually `throw`.

This can happen when the reason it's marked as `throws` because it's part of a `protocol` conformance, but the thing you're calling is something you wrote, and in your case, you know it doesn't ever throw.  In that case `try!` is OK.  But if it's not your code you're calling, or if you're in doubt, always assume that any function marked `throws` can actually throw, so you need to handle it.